# get full directory in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

hi all I have made a function

```
function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()){
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $key => $value){
$path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
if(!is_dir($path)) {
$results[] = $path;
} else if(is_dir($path) && $value != "." && $value != "..") {
getDirContents($path, $results);
$results[] = $path;
}
}

return $results;
}
```

and I am calling it in like

```
$value = $this->getDirContents("/var/www/staging/public/files/rgerger");
```

way from my controller by I am uable to get the full details of the folder I mean the directories and the subdirectories with all contents ..
scandir is on only giving the folder under the target folder which is only scaned but this is not giving me the content of the child folder upto the end.

Comment: I would suggest checking out the SPL [`DirectoryItterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) or [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php). These are built in classes designed specifically to iterate file system directories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of the recursive method call back to the caller.

My (untested) example

```
function getDirectoryContents($dir)
{
    $files = [];

    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        foreach(scandir($dir) as $key => $fileName) {

            $filePath = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName);

            if ($fileName == '.' || $fileName == '..') {
                continue;
            }

            if (is_dir($filePath)) {
                $files[] = getDirectoryContents($filePath);
            } else {
                $files[] = $fileName;
            }
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

As per my comment, you can also use the SPL [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) which is PHP's inbuilt OOP solution for iterating the file system.